# Download Files from FTP to Client PC

Tags: c#, ftp

In my application I have a requirement where the client/user needs to download video files from the ftp server to their local machine.

By using the below code i can able to download the files from ftp,but it only saves on my application server not in local client pc.
I want to download the files to client pc and it should ask dialog box before download.

My code is following,

```
        string ResponseDescription = "";
        string PureFileName = new FileInfo(filename).Name;
        string DownloadedFilePath = @"E:\\aa\\" + PureFileName;
        String downloadUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", "ftp://abcd.int/", filename);
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(downloadUrl);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        req.UseBinary = true;
        req.Proxy = null;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(DownloadedFilePath, FileMode.Create);
            int ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (ReadCount > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                ReadCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
            fs.Close();
            stream.Close();
```

Comment: Are there two applications? A web server and a thick client?

Comment: Where is `E` drive? Is it on the server, is it a local HDD or is it a mapped drive?

Comment: FileStream file = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(MyLocalFile));

Comment: Where are that code running? Sounds like it's executed in the Server, but the code is for an client application. You have to create a FTP server in your server application

Comment: @Aron: Why a -1? New user and probably no accustomed to the SO rules yet. Closing as a duplicate is enough.

Comment: @jgauffin undone...misread the question...Just realised its actually a legit question.

Comment: @JeremyThompson : E drive is a local HDD

Comment: @Civa If i proceed this way its shows error like its not a valid url.can you plz give an code example.